# Vue JS, disable radio based on conditions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 buttons, 1 to create an ungraded quiz, and one to create a graded quiz
this is the one to create an ungraded quiz

```
<additional-quiz-button
                quiz-type="ungraded"
                id-type="pre"
                :quiz-id="form.pre_quiz_id"
                @emitAddQuiz="goToChooseQuiz"
                @emitQuizList="goToQuizList"
              />
```

Here I have 2 radio within a radiogroup, both radio will be disabled if the quiztype is ungraded.

```
<v-radio-group
              v-model="selectedQuizType"
              class="ma-0"
              :disabled="quizType.is_disabled"
            >
              <v-row no-gutters>
                <v-col
                  cols="4"
                  class="radio-cont"
                >
                  <div
                    class="pa-3"
                    :class="[
                      selectedQuizType === 'graded' ? 'grey lighten-4' : '',
                    ]"
                  >
                    <v-radio
                      label="Graded"
                      value="graded"
                    />
                  </div>
                </v-col>
                <v-col
                  cols="4"
                  class="radio-cont right"
                >
                  <div
                    class="pa-3"
                    :class="[
                      selectedQuizType === 'ungraded' ? 'grey lighten-4' : '',
                    ]"
                  >
                    <v-radio
                      label="Ungraded"
                      value="ungraded"
                    />
                  </div>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-radio-group>
```

It successfully created a new ungraded quiz, but the problem is when I click on details, and then delete it, it will redirect to the radio again, but this time both radio are not disabled. I want it to still disabled since it was an ungraded quiz.

I've tried disabling it using the :disabled, but then both radio will be disabled because it will set to ungraded in the first time it opens, and I don't want to get the graded or ungraded value based on what the user clicks. I also want to make both radio disabled if the quiztype is ungraded only, if its graded then both are clickable.

Is there any way to fix this ?

By the way this is my method to delete and redirect to the radio's component
Delete

```
if (this.deleteActionType === 'question') {
          await this.deleteQuestionById(
            Number(this.selectedQuestion.id)
          ).finally(() => {
            this.loading.delete = false
            this.isShowModalConfirm = false
          })

          await this.getQuizList()
        }
```

Redirect to radio's component

```
if (!res.questions.length) {
              this.SET_QUIZ_TYPE({ quiz: quiz_type })

              return this.$router.push({
                path: '/insight/online-course/materials/quiz/choose-quiz',
                query: {
                  ...this.$route.query,
                  subchapter_id: res.sub_chapter_id,
                  quiz_id: res.id,
                },
              })
            }
```

Comment: in the `:disabled` attribute make an statement like this: `:disabled="quizType.is_disabled || quizType === 'ungraded'"`